# Guice change binding by property (string in external text file)/ on runtime

Tags: java, guice

how to change/set a binding by a property/string given in a property/text file? in my case i want to implement a kind of "demo mode".
In normal mode a property gives an url to an external service but if url is "demo" the binding of the according interface should be changed like this:

normal:

```
bind(SasDatenProvider.class).to(SasDataProviderHttpImpl.class);
```

demo

```
bind(SasDataProvider.class).to(SasDataProviderFileImpl.class);
```

how to achieve that?
thx in advance

Comment: Does the property value change at runtime or it is set only once?

Comment: we are talking about a gwt app. so the property is changed before deployment (between compile and runtime ;-)). it is used to initialize/instantiate some stuff. my solution for the moment is: the normal implementation gets the demo implementation injected and uses this if "demo" property is set - i don't feel very comfortable about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a method annotated with `@Provides` in your module. Then you can do something like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Provides
    SasDatenProvider provideSas(SasDataProviderHttpImpl http, 
        SasDataProviderFileImpl file){

        boolean isDemo = false; /* do you property lookup logic here */

        return isDemo ? file : http;
    }
}
```

You can read more about `@Provides`-methods in the guice docs:
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods

If your don't want this kind of logic in you module, you can consider creating your own provider:
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings

Comment: thx!
i am using @Provides already. is it possible to inject dependencies in provide-methods? i need a "serverConfig".

Comment: Yes, you can just add you dependencies to your @Provides method signature