# how to achieve dynamic binding in Google-Guice?

Tags: java, guice, restlet-2.0

I am trying to implement service façade into services to support backward compatibility.

However, I am facing problem in Guise dynamic binding. I need to bind respective implementer class depending upon the version requested by client applications.

Does anyone having idea how to achieve dynamic binding in Google-Guice?

Comment: I answered a very simliar question yesterday:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257863/guice-change-binding-by-property-string-in-external-text-file-on-runtime/8319512#8319512

Answer (score 2):

You can go with binding [annotations](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations):

```
bind(Facade.class).annotatedWith(VersionOne.class).to(OldFacade.class);
bind(Facade.class).annotatedWith(VersionTwo.class).to(NewFacade.class);
```

and have code like:

```
@Inject @VersionOne Facade oldFacade;
@Inject @VersionTwo Facade newFacade;
if (version == 1)
    return oldFacade
else
    return newFacade;
```

Or you can use [multibindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings):

```
MapBinder<Integer, Facade> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), Integer.class, Facade.class);
mapBinder.addBinding(1).to(OldFacade.class);
mapBinder.addBinding(2).to(NewFacade.class);
```

and then you use it like so:

```
@Inject Map<Integer, Facade> facadeMap;
return facadeMap.get(version);
```